# Dygraph in Phyton : How to remove label but still use its values in the graph?

Tags: javascript, python, dygraphs

I am working with Dygraph in python. I want to remove a label from the legend. If you look into the example photo attached bellow you can see "A:2.77   B:2.29". Is it possible to remove the B label, but still use its values and to be displayed in the graph?

Currenlty, in my project `self.page().runJavaScript(f'g.updateOptions({{file:{file},labels:{labels}}});')` is getting the calculated labels and their values and displaying them. However, if I go and remove part of it , it will be removed from the graph as well.

```
self.exampleCalculated.emit({'Price (Next 2 days)': example_forecast['price1'][0:48], 'SystemPrice': systemPrice[0:48], 'Other': otherPrice[0:48]})
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyrIV.png)

Comment: `dygraphs` is a very efficient time series viz library. However, the Python support is very scarse.